# Open Microsoft Teams Client via URL

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to know if it is possible to build a url with only the team sitecollection url which opens up a specific team in your teams client.

e.g. https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/THESITECOLLECTION_URL

Or is it only possbile with the group id of the team?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, just the group ID of the team, e.g. `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/19%<GUID>%40thread.skype/conversations?groupId=<AAD_GROUP_ID>&tenantId=<TENANT_ID>`

Comment: That's sad - thank you anyway... Do you know if there is a way to get the GUID out of the SiteCollection URL? Is there a service for something like that?